# Java Game Collision System Freezes Window

Tags: java, collision-detection, slick2d, code-organization

I am trying to make a message based collision system for a game test, where all objects are stored in an ArrayList that is iterated through and all objects are checked against all other objects. If two objects collide a Message is sent to both of them and currently it does a sysout (print) when this happens. My code so far is below, I have included the classes I think are relevant but if another class is involved I can post that as well. (I am using Slick2D and LWJGL)

```
public class MyGame extends BasicGame {

private ArrayList<GameObject> objects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue();
CollisionSystem collisionSystem = new CollisionSystem(objects, messageQueue);

public MyGame() {
    super("My Game");
}

public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    // Start up the game window
    try {
        AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new MyGame());
        app.setDisplayMode(500, 400, false);
        app.start();
        app.setVSync(false);
        app.setTargetFrameRate(60);
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
    Image img = new Image("myimage.png", false, Image.FILTER_NEAREST);

    objects.add(new ObjSpriteObject(20, 20, img));
    objects.add(new ObjSpriteObject(15, 20, img));
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
    collisionSystem.update();
    messageQueue.update();

    for (GameObject object : objects) {
        object.update(container, delta);
    }
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    g.scale(3, 3);

    for (GameObject object : objects) {
        object.render(container, g);
    }
}

}
```

MessageQueue

```
public class MessageQueue {

public ArrayList<Message> messages;

public MessageQueue() {
    messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
}

public void update() {
    while (messages.iterator().hasNext()) {
        Message m = messages.iterator().next();
        process(m);
    }
}

private void process(Message m) {
    switch (m.getType()) {
    case 'p':
        System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + m.getData());
        break;
    case 'c':
        m.getReciever().processMessage(m);
    }
}

}
```

ObjSpriteObject

```
public class ObjSpriteObject extends GameObject {

private Image sprite;
protected float vspeed = 0f;
protected float hspeed = 0f;
public boolean hasBB = true;

public ObjSpriteObject(int x, int y, Image sprite) {
    super(x, y);
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.boundingBox = new BoundingBox(this, x, y, 16, 16);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) {
    super.update(container, delta);
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) {
    sprite.draw(x, y);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.draw(getBoundingBox());
}

@Override
public void processMessage(Message m) {
    if (m.getType() == 'c') {
        delete = true;
    }
}

}
```

CollisionSystem

```
public class CollisionSystem {

private ArrayList<GameObject> objects;
private MessageQueue messageQueue;

public CollisionSystem(ArrayList<GameObject> objects, MessageQueue messageQueue) {
    this.objects = objects;
    this.messageQueue = messageQueue;
}

public void update() {

    // Iterate through each BB with each BB
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

        // If object has bounding box
        GameObject ob1 = objects.get(i);
        if (ob1.getBoundingBox() != null) {
            for (int k = 0; k < objects.size(); k++) {

                // If second object has bounding box
                GameObject ob2 = objects.get(i);
                if (ob2.getBoundingBox() != null) {

                    // Check both bounding boxes and send messages if they collide
                    BoundingBox bb1 = objects.get(i).getBoundingBox();
                    BoundingBox bb2 = objects.get(k).getBoundingBox();
                    // System.out.println(bb1 + " " + bb2);
                    if (bb1.collides(bb2) && bb1 != bb2) {
                        messageQueue.messages.add(new Message(bb1.getParent(), bb2.getParent(), 'p', "Collision!"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

When I run this code the game freezes. I feel like it has something to do with it running like a while loop that never exits, but I don't see why it would be doing that if the main game loop is making sure things run on a timer. Why is this code freezing the program?

Comment: Check the collision in another thread

Comment: Why does it need to be run in another thread? Won't that thread just freeze up?